# PuTTY, Xming: Wrong encoding when open browser in lunux terminal

Tags: character-encoding, putty, x11-forwarding, xming

I use PuTTY to create a SSH connection and I want to open a Firefox browser in the terminal. I download the Linux version [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all) and [Xming](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xming).
After that, I go to PuTTY configuration and set enable X11 forwarding, then run Xlaunch. I follow the instructions [here](http://aruljohn.com/info/x11forwarding).

Then I login to the terminal and run Firefox. Everything go right except I cannot get the correct encoding in Firefox. What can I do to solve this problem?

[image: Wrong encoding in Firefox]

Answer (score 0):

Try that :

```
yum install dejavu-lgc-sans-fonts
```